# как получить значение ключа в вложенном списке файла json?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Это фрагмент .json файла

```
[
    {
        "label": "Group",
        "ocr_text": "156123",
        "score": 0.26161095,
        "xmin": 670,
        "xmax": 735,
        "ymin": 705,
        "ymax": 720
    },
    {
        "label": "FIO",
        "ocr_text": "Петров Петр Петрович",
        "score": 0.48486748,
        "xmin": 533,
        "xmax": 737,
        "ymin": 728,
        "ymax": 753
    },
    {
        "label": "cipher",
        "ocr_text": "123456",
        "score": 0.45893905,
        "xmin": 684,
        "xmax": 736,
        "ymin": 764,
        "ymax": 779
    },
    {
        "label": "Work_name",
        "ocr_text": "Теория",
        "score": 0.09009137,
        "xmin": 272,
        "xmax": 733,
        "ymin": 440,
        "ymax": 465
    },
    {
        "label": "Theme",
        "ocr_text": "«Текст»",
        "score": 0.12318355,
        "xmin": 244,
        "xmax": 703,
        "ymin": 478,
        "ymax": 535
    }
```

Данный код позволяет получать мне значение 'ocr_text' в вложенном списке.

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint
with open('response.json', 'r') as f:
    data_file = json.load(f)

def Work(data_file):
    work = data_file['result'][0]['prediction'][0]
    if work['label']=='Work_name':
        print(work['ocr_text'])
    elif work['label']=='Theme':
        print(work['ocr_text'])
    elif work['label']=='Group':
        print(work['ocr_text'])
    elif work['label']=='FIO_Students':
        print(work['ocr_text'])
    elif work['label']=='cipher':
        print(work['ocr_text'])
        return
```

Comment: Спасибо. Буду знать как оформлять вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение основано на полном обходе объекта и поиска заданного ключа, результат собрается в `list`

Предварительная обработка элемента который может попасть в список
происходит в методе **getDict** где ключ и строка собираются в tuple
далее в **getTree** при условии что ключ совпадает происходит заполнение результата.

*вывод*: `['156123', 'Петров Петр Петрович', '123456', 'Теория', '«Текст»']`

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint


with open('response.json', 'r') as f:
  data_file = json.load(f)

class Scanner:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data    
    self.result = []

  def extract(self, key):  
    self.test = key
    self.get_tree(data)
    return self.result

  def get_tree(self, data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
      return self.get_list(data)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
      return self.get_dict(data) 
    elif self.is_primitive(data):
      return data
    self.append_to_result(data)
    return data   
  
  def get_dict(self, obj):
    return list(
      map(lambda x: self.get_tree(tuple(x)), obj.items())
    )

  def get_list(self, arr):
    return list(
      map(lambda x: self.get_tree(x), arr)
    ) 

  def is_primitive(self, data):
    return type(data) in (int, str, bool, ...)
  
  def append_to_result(self, data):
    if isinstance(data, tuple):
      if isinstance(data[1], dict):  
        self.get_tree(data[1])
      if isinstance(data[1], list):  
        self.get_tree(data[1])
      elif data[0] == self.test:
        self.result.append(data[1])
    else:
      print('Error')  

print(Scanner(data_file).extract('ocr_text'))
```

Как сокращенную запись той проверки что в вопросе можно предложить еще такой вариант, он менее гибок хотя при условии что этого достаточно, будет быстрее:

```
listTags = ['Work_name', 'Theme', 'Group', 'FIO_Students', 'cipher']
if work['label'] in listTags: print work['ocr_text']
```

Comment: Спасибо. Многое я еще не знаю. Буду изучать как корректно это сделать.

Comment: Не за что, добавил еще вариант упрощения кода из вопроса возможно тоже пригодится.